# Store networkx graph object

Tags: python, networkx

I have a huge graph with about 5000 nodes that I made it with [networkX](https://networkx.org/). It takes about 30 seconds to create this graph each time I execute my script. After this relatively long time I can run my analysis like `shortest_path` and so on.

My question is, is there any way to store the object of this graph in file or something like this and each time I run my script, networkX read that file and load all of my graph?

Comment: Does it take so long to read in because it is doing a lot of processing of data files?  If so, then saving just the graph in one of the formats supported by networkx may be more efficient. https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/readwrite/index.html

Comment: It take so long because every time I should create my graph. my nodes are in database and I select all of them and add them to graph with `add_node` function.@Joel

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of version 2.6, methods `write_gpickle` and `read_gpickle` are deprecated. Try this instead:

```
import pickle

# save graph object to file
pickle.dump(G, open('filename.pickle', 'wb'))

# load graph object from file
G = pickle.load(open('filename.pickle', 'rb'))
```

Note the options `'wb'` to dump and `'rb'` to load in `open()`.

Comment: Thanks, tested with NetworkX 3.0, works like a charm.

Comment: works in 3.1 as well.

Answer (score 6):

Solution Now Deprecated.

You could use `gpickle` to do this. Assuming your graph is denoted with `G`, you could save it by:

```
nx.write_gpickle(G,'myGraph.gpickle')
```

and load it with

```
G = nx.read_gpickle('myGraph.gpickle')
```

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/readwrite/gpickle.html#pickled-graphs

Comment: Doc says deprecated since version 2.6...

Comment: Deprecation docs: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/release/migration_guide_from_2.x_to_3.0.html#deprecated-code