# How do I import a Networkx graph as input to another python function?

Tags: python, networkx

My python skills are at a beginner level and this is my first time working with Networkx, so this question might be very basic.

I've built a graph G using Networkx, and when I return this graph I get the following:

```
return G
<networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph object at 0x7faf38013250>
```

I then attempt to call the built graph as input in a separate function to plot the graph. I currently call the graph using the DiGraph object name generated when I built the graph.

```
<networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph object at 0x7faf38013250>
```

However, I'm guessing this isn't actually importing the graph to the plotting function because the graph isn't actually stored as a defined object within the plotting function, nor am I importing it from a saved file. I check to see whether the graph is imported to to the plotting function by including the following as the first two lines of code in the plotting function:

```
print(list(G.nodes))
print(list(G.edges))
```

As expected, this produces the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'nodes'
```

Is there a way to save the graph after building it, so that I can call it as input in my plotting function? I've tried exporting the graph using pickle and the pickle.dump function described in another post ([Store networkx graph object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64846222/store-networkx-graph-object)), but it doesn't actually export a file for me.

I'm running Networkx v2.7.1 in python v3.9.12

Thanks!

Comment: If your first function returns a `Graph` object, "save" it in a variable: `G = your_func() ; other_func(G)`

Comment: My first function actually returns two objects, one of which is the graph object. How would I modify your code to save just the one object as G, to then call in the other function? (sorry....newb Q here)

Comment: Assuming the first item is the graph: `G, _ = your_func()`

Comment: Thanks @mozway, that worked exactly as I needed, I now have an object I can easily import to my plotting function. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great, I suggest you to read this nice explanation of how [names](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) work in python